# is it possible to know (server) CPU performance in php?

Tags: php, mysql, cpu

I am new to php environment, recently i developed a web site based on php + mysql. I hosted it on shared hosting. But the problem is they have restrictions on CPU and ram usage. So now i decided to plan for some thing like code which calculates CPU and ram usage and now it if ever it starts to consume more than the its limit so now code have to reduce it, or else creating restore point so that after little bit time it need to be invoked back.

and

```
1.my questions, is it possible to know exact CPU and ram usage.

2.Is it possible to control the code to use less resources.
```

...
thank you .

Comment: I bet you have a massive mysql query and it's not indexed and you are hitting a memory limit. Look into mysql optimization

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, php can do only [sys_getloadavg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPSysInfo library

phpSysInfo is a open source PHP script that displays information about the host being accessed. It will displays things like:

Uptime,CPU,Memory,SCSI, IDE, PCI,Ethernet,Floppy,Video Information

You can always optimize code to use less resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can :

```
"CPU Usage" => $UPTIMESTRING = `uptime`,
```

Also you can use `PHPSysInfo library`